# Value outside of function is different from value inside function

Tags: php

In this elementary code, I check if a record exists with a particular itemId for a particular user and country.

The record returns `1` inside the function, but when it's outside, it's something totally different.

```
function recordExists(&$d) {
    global $conn, $userId, $userCountryCode;

    $sqlFindRecord = "select count(itemId) as recordCount from onr_items_mod where itemTempId = :itemTempId and itemStatus IN(0,5,8) and itemPublishedStatus = 2 and itemUserId = :userId and itemUserCountryCode = :userCountryCode";

    $countRecord = $conn->prepare($sqlFindRecord);

    $countRecord->execute(array(
        ":itemTempId" => $d,
        ":userId" => $userId,
        ":userCountryCode" => $userCountryCode
    ));

    $countRecord->bindColumn('recordCount',$d);

    echo 'This is D '.$d.' ---';

    $row = $countRecord->fetch();

    if($d == 0) {
        return $d;
    } elseif ($d == 1) {
        return $d;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$d = 'US01'

if(recordExists($d) == 0) { //If the function returned 0
    echo $d;
    echo 'Was Zero';
} elseif (recordExists($d) == 1) { //If the function returned 1
    echo $d;
    echo 'Was One';
} else {
    echo $d;
    echo 'Neither Zero or One';
}
```

After I do the above, it's always 'Neither Zero or One'. Why is this? I tried the entire morning, but just cannot figure a way to sort this out.

**This works, but not the above**

```
function counter(&$a) {
    if($a == 0) {
        return $a;
    } elseif ($a == 1) {
        return $a;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$a = 1;

if(counter($a) == 0) {
    echo $a;
} elseIf (counter($a) == 1) {
    echo $a;
} else {
    echo 'Umm...'.$a;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `$d` to the function by reference?

Comment: Because the value of `$d` changes inside the function.

Comment: It would be simpler if you change that and pass by value, then just consume the function's returned value.

Comment: Not sure what's the use of your function. $d is US01 but $a is 1. They are processed differently because your input is different. You're also missing a semicolon after setting $d = 'US01'

Comment: Another potential issue is you return either `0`, `1`, or `false`. Then you use that in an `if .. elseif .. else` block. But, `0` will be regarded as `false` in your checks.

Comment: My idea is to get the value of $d from inside the function, to out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

It will always be 'Neither Zero or One' why? Let's seee how it works

```
1. $d = 'US01'

2. if(recordExists($d) == 0) { //If the function returned 0
3.     echo $d;
4.     echo 'Was Zero';
5. } elseif (recordExists($d) == 1) { //If the function returned 1
6.     echo $d;
7.     echo 'Was One';
8. } else {
9.     echo $d;
10.     echo 'Neither Zero or One';
11. }
```

First `$d` is equal `US01`. It's ok. But after pass line #2 `$d == 1` because you have set it in function (you have pass $d by reference).
So if statement in #2 line will return false beacuse thera are some records in database with itemTempId = 'US01'.

But now in the second if statement in line #5 variable `$d = 1`. So I suposse that you don't have any record with that `itemTempId` in your database. So the second statement (line #5) will also return false.

In my opinion you shouldn't pass it by reference.

**EDIT**

If you want to check if item exist in databse then yopu can ask only once. I really don't know what your goal is. But maybe this will be good

```
$d = 'US01';
$ret = recordExists($d);
if ($ret === 0) {
    echo 'Was zero';
} elseif ($ret === 1) {
    echo 'Was one';
} else {
    echo 'Something else';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to insert that into session variable and retrieve it in another method.
Hope it'll help.